# A two weeks’ notice is - should the indefinite article truly be there?

Tags: grammar, possessives

As far as I know, when the possesive is used, I really should not use articles because it would bind to the same noun.
E.g.:

> A two-day trip
>   Two day's trip

However, I have just found a site which reads:

> A two weeks’ notice is a formal declaration of your intention to
>   resign two weeks from the day you submit it.

Is that truly correct?

F

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should “two weeks vacation” be written “two weeks’ vacation” with a possessive apostrophe?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103849/should-two-weeks-vacation-be-written-two-weeks-vacation-with-a-possessive-a); see also [Should possessive 's be used when there is no possession in the strict sense?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/288877/should-possessive-s-be-used-when-there-is-no-possession-in-the-strict-this-is/288899#288899).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I did read these, and they did not really answer my question,.

Comment: The _two weeks' notice_ example and the 'With _nine days wonder_, the trend seems generally towards the dropping of the 'associative rather than true possessive' apostrophe-s, but this is not the only practice followed.' extracts **certainly** address your question. But 'a two-day trip' is certainly far more natural sounding than 'a two day's trip', and 'a four-week notice' is probably still quite a lot less common than 'a four weeks' notice'. Google Ngrams should reinforce this view.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sure, I understand the trend but from the grammar perspective, one still should be correct and the other should not..? Or if not correct, more grammatical?

Comment: Grammar may evolve more slowly than word usage, but it still changes. At times, conflicting usages exist, sometimes quite harmoniously, but arguments are almost inevitable between hyper-prescriptivists (legalists) and hyper-descriptivists (radicals / the progressives) over what should be considered acceptable. Svartvik & Quirk suggest a 5-point scale of acceptability. . Think about the vastly more common title _working mens clubs_ (no apostrophe). It has to be accepted as not incorrect nowadays, but traditionalists are spitting feathers over the appearance of this strange new word _mens_.

Comment: As for use of the article, 'a nine days/day's/days wonder' is a fixed expression (though I've never seen it pluralised: 2 nine-d...). The same is true of 'a 2/4 weeks' notice'. You can consider these as single lexemes, compound nouns, as in 'my two-weeks' notice' (given in the first link above), a dogs home, a working men(')s club, a dead man's handle (deducible in the second linked thread).... Below are the Google Ngrams showing usage:

Comment: [a two-day trip,a two days' trip,a four week notice,a four-week notice,a four weeks' notice](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+two-day+trip%2Ca+two+days%27+trip%2Ca+four+week+notice%2Ca+four-week+notice%2Ca+four+weeks%27+notice&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20two%20-%20day%20trip%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20two%20days%20%27%20trip%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20four%20weeks%20%27%20notice%3B%2Cc0) (I think you need to click on the blue button).

Comment: In my opinion, giving two weeks' notice isn't declaring you're intending to resign at the end of the two-week period, it is itself the resignation. Exactly when your last day at work will be is then subject to negotiation even if you nominate a date.