# When does the word 'months' get an apostrophe?

Tags: apostrophe

Is it '12 month's remuneration', '12 months' remuneration' or '12 months remuneration'? New Oxford Style Manual says it does not get an apostrophe is not used in 'adjectival constructions' e.g. three months pregnant. Confused.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should “two weeks vacation” be written “two weeks’ vacation” with a possessive apostrophe?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103849/should-two-weeks-vacation-be-written-two-weeks-vacation-with-a-possessive-a) But see also [Should possessive 's be used when there is no possession in the strict sense?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/288877/should-possessive-s-be-used-when-there-is-no-possession-in-the-strict-this-is/288899#288899), where "...

Comment: with _nine days wonder_, the trend seems generally towards the dropping of the 'associative rather than true possessive' apostrophe-s, but this is not the only practice followed." is found.

Answer (score 2):

*Three months pregnant* is an adjectival phrase: its head is that adjective *pregnant*, and syntactically the modifier cannot be possessive.

*Twelve months' remuneration* is a noun phrase - its head is the noun *remuneration* and so the modifier **can** be a possessive. Syntactically, it doesn't **have** to be a possessive, but it can be. This is an area where the language is in flux.

Traditionally it is regarded as a possessive. *Twelve months' remuneration* can be paraphrased as *a remuneration of twelve months* (though this paraphrase is not idiomatic in Modern English). *Months* there is plural, so in the original phrase it takes the plural possessive *months'*.

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms:

1. "X months' + **noun (or noun phrase, etc.)**" requires an apostrophe as it means "[the amount of of] X months' [worth] of noun" (e.g. Three months' wages = three months [worth] of wages = **the value of the wages for three months**), the genitive apostrophe is required.
2. "X months + modifier (adjective/adverb/adjunct)", e.g. "Three months **in jail**" or "Three months **pregnant**" or "He used three months **wisely**", there is no apostrophe.

Thus, *months* in "three months of hard work" will have no apostrophe, as "of hard work" is an adjunct/adjectival phrase.

But "three months' hard work" will have an apostrophe, as "hard work" is a noun phrase.

Comment: Don't you think this question suits English Language Learners site better? It's interesting that you kindly left an answer for this. I have no clue what your criterion is.

Answer (score -1):

It should be "12 months' [worth of] remuneration," because it's quasi-possessive in such constructions: "a month's pay."

In constructions indicating length of time that a condition has persisted - "He turned in the homework two months late", or "She was five months pregnant", or "We finished the project four months early" - no apostrophe would be used.

A good rule of thumb is probably: use the possessive apostrophe for nouns ("This book represents eighteen months' hard work"); use no apostrophe for adjectives ("Somehow the task force had fallen eight months behind").

Comment: Not sure why I'm getting downvoted lol. I was the first to respond to the question (so I didn't copy from anyone else), and all of the answers that are being upvoted agreed that my original answer was correct: use an apostrophe with nouns, use no apostrophe with adjectives.