# Use of singular in the title “The Three-Body Problem”

Tags: grammatical-number, attributive-nouns, measuring-units

The title of the Chinese book *三体*, written by Liu Cixin, was translated as *The Three-Body Problem*. This is also the name of a [famous physics problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem).

My question is: why do we say the three-*body* and not the three-*bodies* or the three-*bodys*? There are three bodies involved, not one, and the plural of *body* is *bodies*.

Comment: Draw a six-inch line.   I need a ten foot ladder.  They went on a six mile run. **body** is a unit there.

Comment: There's also Sherlock Holmes' [three-pipe problem](https://www.visitportsmouth.co.uk/conan-doyle/you-dont-know-sherlock-holmes-yet/cabinet-of-curiosities/three-pipes#:~:text=This%20is%20a%20quote%20taken,to%20me%20for%20fifty%20minutes.%E2%80%9D) - he estimates that it will take him the length of time necessary to smoke 3 pipes of tobacco to figure it out. (NB _Bodys_ is not a valid plural.)

Comment: @TimR So when a name is used as a unit, it must be used in its singular form?

Comment: @KateBunting You’re right, I badly read [this](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/body).

Comment: Yes, when a word is being used as a unit, it is singular.   A four-room apartment. A ten-day trip.    A three-week vacation.  A two-second gap in the recording.  A ten-degree difference. A five-alarm fire.

Comment: A three-dog night, a four-horse open sleigh, a five-man crew.

Comment: A five-star review :-)

Comment: Similarly *three point line/goal/shot* in basketball, *two man job* or similar phrases, *seven year itch*, *four day week*...

Comment: It's not when it's used as a unit, it's when it's used to qualify something. Contrast: "It's a ten-mile road." vs "The road is ten miles long".

Answer (score 4):

This is **not** an unreasonable question.

- the [Six Nations Championship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Nations_Championship) (rugby union) has just finished, and the
- the [Three Peaks Challenge](https://www.threepeakschallenge.uk/national-three-peaks-challenge/) is a well known endurance event in the UK.
- Tall Ships Races [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tall_Ships_Races#:%7E:text=The%20races%20are%20designed%20to,in%20company%22%20between%20the%20legs.)]
- a [nine days wonder](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/288877/should-possessive-s-be-used-when-there-is-no-possession-in-the-strict-this-is) (one of various spellings)

all have strings of the form [numeral] + [plural-form noun before the head noun] + [head noun]. The first three examples are fixed in form.

But these are not typical; usually, even after a numeral or plural-triggering quantifier like 'many', nouns used prenominally are in the singular form.

I'll list Tim's examples with measures (units):

- a six-inch line
- a ten foot ladder
- a six mile run
- a two-second gap
- a ten-degree difference
- a two-year-old boy
- a ten-gallon hat

and add his, Kate's, Peter's and Stuart's examples with other prenominal nouns ('quasi-units?'):

- a five-alarm fire
- a three-pipe problem
- a four-room apartment
- a three-dog night
- a four-horse open sleigh
- an eight-man crew
- a five-star review
- the seven year itch
- a three-piece suite
- a 38-piece orchestra
- the ten step program
- a two-horse town / race
- a 21-gun salute
- a three-ring circus
- a three-point turn
- a three-bar electric fire
- Two Gun Tex of Texas (!!)

So *the Three-body Problem* is of the usual form – and not an exception –  as looking up the term will confirm).

Comment: The point is that all your examples should have hyphens as a compound adjective, or at least are treated as a compound, and adjectives are not inflected for number. Hence they are all singular. It is arguable that your first four examples should have apostrophes.

Comment: Usage, not prescriptive rules, drives / ultimately governs acceptability. 'The Ten Step Program' is found with and without the hyphen. "Two Gun Tex of Texas" is a song title, unhyphenated. The seven year itch is usually but not always found hyphenated; the film title was unhyphenated.  // The move to drop apostrophes from usages such as 'working mens club' is well under way; the attributive noun v adjective divide is murky.  Another complication making the simplistic analysis suspect: as Erik Kowal ...

Comment: has said elsewhere, 'you could describe a successful tennis player equally as "a five-times winner of the Australian Open" and "a five-time winner of the Australian Open" '. _But adjectives don't inflect for number in English_ ....

Comment: No, you couldn't.

Comment: Many do. 400 000+ (raw) hits on Google for "three(-)times winner", including many respectable sources (Nature, The Times, Keir Starmer, Bonhams ...). Ludwig Guru even has '"three times winner" is correct and usable in written English'.